# Custom URI handling: xdg-open and Firefox work, but Chrome doesn't

Tags: chrome, xdg-open, xdg

I'm trying to configure my Linux environment to open `obsidian://` URIs using the Obsidian app (see [Using Obsidian URI](https://help.obsidian.md/Advanced+topics/Using+obsidian+URI)).

This is the flow I'm using. I'm doing this on a clean Ubuntu machine to make sure it reproduces:

1. The `Obsidian.AppImage` file is stored in `~/obsidian` alongside an `icon.jpg` file. The `AppImage` file has execute permissions.
2. This is my `~/.local/share/applications/obsidian.desktop` file's content:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Obsidian
   Exec=/home/rachum/obsidian/Obsidian.AppImage %u
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=/home/rachum/obsidian/icon.png  
   StartupWMClass=obsidian
   X-AppImage-Version=0.8.15
   Comment=Obsidian
   Categories=Office;
   MimeType=text/html;x-scheme-handler/obsidian;
   ```
3. I've run `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/`
4. Using `xdg-open` works as intended:

   ```
   xdg-open "obsidian://new?vault=notes&name=note&content=content"
   ```

   This command line opens the Obsidian app with the new note and content.
5. In Firefox (preinstalled), typing the above URI into the URL bar also opens the Obsidian app with the new note and content.
6. I installed Google Chrome by downloading the `.deb` file from the official Chrome site and running `dpkg -i <.deb file>`
7. Typing the above URI in Chrome just redirects me to a Google search for "obsidian://new?vault=notes&name=note&content=content".

Why is Chrome not respecting the XDG configuration?

---

Update #1: adding more details to answer comment.

My `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` file looks like this:

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/obsidian=obsidian.desktop
```

My `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` file looks like this:

```
[MIME Cache]
text/html=obsidian.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/obsidian=obsidian.desktop;
```

Comment: have you updated `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` ?

Comment: @binarysta - yes, see update #1..

Comment: define "a clean Ubuntu machine"

Comment: I'm creating a fresh Ubuntu droplet in Digital Ocean, installing GNOME and then proceeding to the steps described above.

Comment: I would try and reproduce with a live install DVD inside a VM, because the issue is probably caused by the server-image that is used over at digitalocean. Also, the version is pretty important 18.04 ? 20.10 ? 21.04?

Answer (score 3):

> Why is Chrome not respecting the XDG configuration?

Your assessment is incorrect, Chrome does use xdg-open. The screenshot below demonstrates that both google-chrome and chromium will prompt to open "special links" with xdg-open.

[image: prompt for xdg-open]

### Reset the always-run option

If you have previously accepted the "Always open files of this type" dialog, then you will need to reset this setting. The option you want to clear is this:

> open certain file types automatically after downloading

To get to this option:

1. open the special URL chrome://settings/ in chrome
2. scroll down and click on the advanced link at the bottom
3. [Click the chevron on "andvanced" to reveal more settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl6Ja.png)
4. there is an option under downloads that is only there if you have set at least one file to run instead of download
5. [Click on the "clear"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K41wm.png) button next to "open certain file types automatically after downloading"

There is no option to reset only some file types. You will notice that the button disappears afterwards.

Advanced settings:
[image: advanced-settings]

Clear always run settings:
[image: clear-settings]

---

### Check that URL is not blocked.

> Applies to Linux users who sign in to a managed account on Chrome browser.
> Using your preferred JSON file editor:
>
> Go to your /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed folder.
> Create or update a JSON file and enter URLs as needed:
> In URLBlocklist, add the URLs that you want to block.
> In URLAllowlist, add the URLs that you want users to access.

You can verify the currently loaded policies with: chrome://policy/

Source:

- https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532419

---

### Reset the chrome protocol handler

```
$ grep -r ~/.config/google-chrome/ -e protocol_handler -l
```

If you use the default profile, then this is the file to edit:

- $HOME/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences

If you are using multiple profiles, the Preferences file will be in google-chrome/Profile 2, google-chrome/Profile 3 etc.

Clear the settings for specific protocols as needed, obsidian:// in this case.

```
$ jq <  /home/jaroslav/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences  \
    | grep protocol_handler -C 2

  "custom_handlers": {
    "enabled": true,
    "ignored_protocol_handlers": [
      {
        "last_modified": "13276367110202441",
--
      }
    ],
    "registered_protocol_handlers": []
  },
  "custom_links": {
--
        },
        "ppapi_broker": {},
        "protocol_handler": {},
        "safe_browsing_url_check_data": {},
        "sensors": {},
```

On more recent versions of chrome, you can control this via the web-ui. Just open this special URL

- chrome://settings/content/fileHandlers
- chrome://settings/handlers

You want to select this:

> Web apps can ask to open types of files

And

> Sites can ask to handle protocols

---

references:

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=152993
- https://www.ghacks.net/2015/10/29/how-to-open-downloads-in-chrome-automatically/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986354/how-to-prevent-popping-up-xdg-open-dialogue-from-ubuntu-chrome-while-opening-spe
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/465586/how-to-reset-external-protocol-handler-in-chrome

Comment: Thanks, but all of these solutions suggest that Chrome somehow got configured incorrectly at one point. But I'm running the above steps on a freshly installed machine, so I'm running this immediately after installing Chrome.

Comment: This is the only answer, and I do really appreciate the effort here - so I give you the bounty. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was `sudo update-desktop-database` I also had the same problem and after searching for a while I found this: https://superuser.com/questions/162092/how-can-i-register-a-custom-protocol-with-xdg